# $\int_0^{\infty}g(y)e^{-a_n|y|}dy=\int_{-\infty}^0g(y)e^{-a_n|y|}dy=0$ for all $n$ ,$g(y)=0$ ae?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a measurable function $g:R \to R$

$i,n \in N$

And  some sequence $ \{a_i\}$ such that $\lim_{i \to \infty}a_i=+\infty$

$|g(y) |\le e^{-|y|}$ for all $y$

$\int_0^{\infty}g(y)e^{-a_n|y|}dy=\int_{-\infty}^0g(y)e^{-a_n|y|}dy=0$ for all $n$

Is it true $g(y)=0$ almost everywhere ?

Comment: You might try introducing the auxiliary sets $E_k = \{|g| > 1/k\}$.

Comment: @Alex Ortiz pls explain